# How to analyze deeply linked objects in Eclipse MAT

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-dump, eclipse-mat

I am trying to analyze a memory leak using Eclipse MAT. I already know that the issue is caused by an object that is essentally a linked list, e.g. something like this:

```
class Obj {
  byte[] data;
  Obj next;
}
```

The problem is that it is very deep (around 40,000 elements), and it's also not the standard `LinkedList`, so MATs support for that is no available here.

Having the first element, I'm trying to get to the bottom of the list, but I couldn't find anything better than simply right clicking `next` and choosing `Go To`, which at 40,000 elements would take ages. Is there a way to use some kind of scripting to get to the bottom of the linked stack easily?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to use some kind of scripting to get to the bottom of
>   the linked stack easily?

What you could do is use [`jhat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) to rely on the `Object Query Language` also know as `OOL` (which a SQL-like query language to query heap dumps) to execute a query against your heap dump.

#### 1. Launch `jhat`

```
jhat <path-to-my-heap-dump-file>
```

This will start a web server by default on the port `7000`

#### 2. Go to the `OOL` page

1. Go to http://localhost:7000/
2. Click on `Execute Object Query Language (OQL) query` in `Other Queries`'s section

#### 3. Execute my query

Assuming that you want to get the instance of `Obj` whose field `next` is `null`, the query to launch will be of type:

```
select o from my.package.Obj o where o.next == null
```

You will then find all instances of the class `my.package.Obj` whose field `next` is `null`. Just click on the instances of your choice to get deeper information about them.

For more complex queries, you can refer to the doc available from http://localhost:7000/oqlhelp/.

---

Another way to do the same thing is to use [`jvisualvm`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) which is much more user friendly but also more memory consuming than `jhat`.

1. Start `jvisualvm`
2. Go to `File/Load...`
3. Choose your heap dump file then click `Open`, it will open your heap dump
4. Then click on `OQL Console`
5. In the `Query Editor`'s section put your query and click on `Execute`
6. Your result will then appear in the `Query Results`'s section, you will then be able to go deeper on the instances of your choice

Comment: getting closer with this, apparently there are still quite a lot of leaf objects, but fortunately not as much as the original depth of the large objects. Going to play with OQL filters. Note: MAT also supports OQL